# crontab issue with Django project in virtual environment :"mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012"

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, cron

I have a django-project were there is a task to send weekly email notifications to all the users. Here are the steps of approach:-

1.Created a Management command for sending weekly-email notifications.

2.edited the crontab as below :-

```
$ sudo crontab -e
#For testing purposes I have edited as below
 1 * * * * pathto/virtualenv pathto/manage.py notify_email
```

3.restarted the crontab

```
$sudo service cron restart
cron stop/waiting
cron start/running, process 16218
```

4.to check the log status I tried the below

```
$tail -n 10 /var/log/syslog

Mar 19 13:36:08 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 cron[15293]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Mar 19 13:37:01 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 CRON[15364]: (praneeth) CMD (/home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/bin/python3.4 /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site/manage.py notify_about_changes)
Mar 19 13:37:02 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 postfix/sendmail[15367]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Mar 19 13:37:02 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 CRON[15363]: (praneeth) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Mar 19 13:38:01 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 CRON[15416]: (praneeth) CMD (/home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/bin/python3.4 /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site/manage.py notify_about_changes)
Mar 19 13:38:01 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 postfix/sendmail[15418]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Mar 19 13:38:01 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 CRON[15415]: (praneeth) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Mar 19 13:39:01 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 CRON[15457]: (praneeth) CMD (/home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/bin/python3.4 /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site/manage.py notify_about_changes)
Mar 19 13:39:01 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 postfix/sendmail[15459]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Mar 19 13:39:01 praneeth-Latitude-E6400 CRON[15456]: (praneeth) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
```

5.I have gone through the following [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1468184) for solution to look at mail in the terminal and found 1 to 43 entries when I sudo into mail like below

```
$sudo mail
N  1 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:21   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N  2 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:22   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N  3 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:23   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N  4 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:24   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N  5 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:25   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N  6 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:26   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N  7 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:27   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N  8 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:28   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N  9 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:29   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 10 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:30   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 11 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:31   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 12 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:32   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 13 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:33   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 14 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:34   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 15 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:35   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 16 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:36   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 17 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:37   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 18 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:38   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 19 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:39   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 20 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:40   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 21 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:41   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 22 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:42   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 23 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:43   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 24 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:44   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 25 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:45   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 26 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:46   22/1194  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 27 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:47   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 28 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:48   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 29 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:49   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 30 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:50   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 31 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:51   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 32 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:52   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 33 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:53   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 34 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:54   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 35 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:55   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 36 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:56   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 37 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:57   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 38 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:58   54/3457  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 39 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 14:59   21/1323  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 40 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 15:00   21/1323  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 41 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 15:01   21/1323  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 42 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 15:02   21/1323  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
 N 43 Cron Daemon        Mon Mar 16 15:03   21/1323  Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneet
```

If I type 1 for instance, i got the message like below:-
Message  9:

```
From root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400.corp.ad.wrs.com  Mon Mar 16 14:29:02 2015
Return-Path: <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400.corp.ad.wrs.com>
Date: Mon, 16 Mar 2015 14:29:01 -0400
From: root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400.corp.ad.wrs.com (Cron Daemon)
To: root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400.corp.ad.wrs.com
Subject: Cron <root@praneeth-Latitude-E6400> cd /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site && /home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/bin/python3.4 manage.py notify_about_changes
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Status: R
```

**other side of solution to send weekly email notification** "I was able to send the automatic email notifications comfortably through kronos, django-celery with rabbitmq broker. ***But I would like to make the task as simple as possible with crontab***."

I would appreciate guidance Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm able to resolve the first three steps in crontab to send email notifiactions by re-editing the crontab as

```
$*/1 * * * *  /home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/bin/python3.4 /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site/manage.py notify_about_changes --settings=project.settings.development
```

Also I figured out steps 4 and 5 is not a right approach to check for log status of crontab.

Comment: I am stuck with same problem can you please help me. My question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66044229/cron-job-in-linux-is-setup-using-django-but-not-working   please help me I've already wasted 4-5 days trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519519) can help you with the postfix error that cron throws:

A possible solution is to reconfigure postfix. Reconfiguration can be done using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

The user interface will be displayed. On each screen, select the following values:

- Ok
- Internet Site
- NONE
- mail.example.com
- mail.example.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
- No
- 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0/24
- Yes
- 0
- +
- all

You may have to edit `/etc/postfix/main.conf` to update the mail hostname.

Comment: Operating System I use is linux mint 17 and does it needs to be Ubuntu machine to run crontab more smoothly

Comment: I have not used linux mint but I had understood that it was based on ubuntu, the solution of the link not apply for you?

Comment: I tried to reconfigure the crontab using $sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
and got the following traceback  http://pastie.org/10040392